# how to slice bytes object when i try to slice it give me int number?

Tags: python, html, urllib, google-finance

I am trying to get live tick from google finance site using 
urllib,request but  it returns a lot of data but I want to select the only price so how do I select that without using loops **I want that thing from HTML ["INFY","Infosys Ltd","894.70","-0.90","chr"]

```
import urllib.request
response = urllib.request.urlopen('https://www.google.com/finance?q=NSE:INFY')
html = response.read()
```

Comment: Interesting dupe... you should probably look at those answers.

Comment: FOR YOU INFORMATION GOOGLE FINANCE API STOP WORKING AS OF 6 SEP 2017 HTTP ERROR 404

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the issue expressed in your title, `response.read()` will give you a `bytes` object.
Convert it to a string to manipulate it more conveniently:

```
html = str(response.read(), encoding="utf8")
```

The `encoding` optional argument indicates the encoding of the text represented by the `bytes` object - most likely UTF-8.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Oh right I typed this in a hurry. Modifying this right away

Comment: `I typed this in a hurry` why were you hurrying? :p

Comment: now i have to look what position is price that i am looking for i think i will loop for the location of price

Comment: any idea how to extract price from string

Comment: @LakhanPahuja You should definitely ask a new question related to that precise new problem.